# What is behind the recent surge in settler activity in the West Bank?

Tags: israel, palestine, colonialism

The Guardian [reports](https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2024/jan/05/middle-east-crisis-live-updates-antony-blinken-israel-palestine-gaza-hamas) an "unprecedented surge" in illegal settler activity in the West Bank. The Peace Now report that they cite claims that this is because settlers are "exploiting" the war in Gaza "to create facts on the ground". Is this accurate? Is the activity mainly an opportunistic land grab, or are there other factors driving it?

Comment: The number of West Bank "settlers" [was already the rise](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/israel-advances-peak-number-west-bank-settlement-plans-2023-watchdog-2023-07-13/) *before* the war in Gaza, so the war can't be the reason.

Comment: Neither old locals nor recent settlers lead a charmed life in the territories. One has to see that Israelis see the locals there as supporting the terrorism of Oct. 7, as polls show, and react to them as though they are the same aggressors.

Comment: The very article you link says that there is implicit support for the settlers from the Israeli government and currently practically no enforcement against actions by Israelis so I don't think there is any more reaason then that they currently can get away with it.